# Populating multi dimensional arrays with 0

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to populate part of an array with 0's and wondering if there was a better way then to loop through it.

I know I could use `Dim tempArr as double` to do this but the first column in the array contains strings.

I'm currently using

```
Dim tempArr as Variant

ReDim tempArr(1 To 6, 1 To 1 + (EndWeek - (BeginWeek - 1)))
tempArr(1, 1) = "Monday - Friday"
tempArr(2, 1) = "Saturday"
tempArr(3, 1) = "Sunday"
tempArr(4, 1) = "Bank Holiday"
tempArr(5, 1) = "Annual Leave"
tempArr(6, 1) = "Apprentice"
For i = 1 To 6
    For j = 2 To UBound(tempArr, 2)
        tempArr(i, j) = CDbl(0)
    Next j
Next i
```

But surely there's a better way?

Comment: There's no way around it if you're using an array of `Variants`. I note that the only part of this array that is a string is the first 'row' (presumably headers). I guess this array is to be written to a worksheet  - if so, I'd be inclined to have two arrays: one with just the headers and the other with all your doubles.

Comment: @Ambie you're correct that it is being written to a worksheet but it is stored as the value of a dictionary key first hence only the one array